# how to get data from the url in php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Hi guys I've been working with `$_GET['whatever']` now this time I need something that I've never had done before I've seen this url `domain.com/author/name_of_user` and my question is how do I get data in that kind of URL? I've been looking for answers and all they say is `$_GET['']`; 
so example I have this link `http://localhost/domain/attachments.php`
how do I change this one to `http://localhost/domain/attachments/` in the first place? and how will I be able to get data from that is it from `$_GET['']`? please help me I'm really confused

Comment: are you want a way to pass the values through a hidden way...??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called URL rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Those are links to url rewritting in Apache / IIS.

In short, it takes: `http://localhost/domain/attachments.php` and "transform" (or rewrite) it to 
`http://localhost/domain/attachments` (or whatever you prefer).

Normally it is used to improve SEO.

You can still use $_GET normally because it's just a transformation, in the end you still have whatever.php?var=value&.... only that it shows differently for the browser.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretts simple to rewrite a URL. Apache comes with a mod called `mod_rewrite` that handles this. The only thing you need to do is write some rules in your `.htaccess`.

I recommend you to read this article: [htaccess Tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Apache's rewrite module in order to rewrite your URLs.

In your specific case - after you have activated the `mod_rewrite` - try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain/attachments/?$ /domain/attachments.php
```

However this doesn't affect your `$_GET` array in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You will need .htaccess file at the root of your website that will rewrite your website URLs from example.com/index.php?var1=12&var2=23 to something similar to example.com/pagename/12/23
Here are some basics of using .htaccess for URL rewriting: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html